# How to set default stings.xml using AppCompatDelegate in android?

Tags: android, locale

`AppCompatDelegate` is a new way to change application's locale according to user's preferred language which can be done as follow:

```kotlin
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(
   LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(userSelectedLocaleTag)
)
```

My problem with this delegate is that when device's default language is any language other than **English**, I cannot force the app to use default `strings.xml`.

I tried to use below code in `Application` class but it does not work (I do not have english `strings.xml` file. I just have default xml for english):

```kotlin
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en"))
```

I tested this on **Android SDK 33**